# Deny access to previous commits on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

There is a way to deny a user on GitLab to access previous versions of the code?

Answer (score 0):

No. The whole point of Git is that it is a transitive closure of commits, which necessarily includes all the previous versions as well.